# Android: nullpointerexception attempt to read from null array

Tags: java, android

I have a suspicion that the makeLine method created a null array somehow, but I'm not quite sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! A snippet of my code is below:

```
public void all() {

        int[][] line = new int[3][];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && line[i - 1][0] == 2) { // Error occurs at this line
                int start = line[i - 1][2];
                int pos = line[i - 1][1];
                int xy = line[i - 1][3]++;

                if (line[i - 1][3] == 1) {
                    int end = y()[1];
                    line[i] = new int[]{1, start, end, pos, xy};
                } else {
                    int end = x()[1];
                    line[i] = new int[]{1, start, end, pos, xy};
                }
            } else {
                line[i] = makeLine();
            }
        }
}

private int[] makeLine() {
                Random r = new Random();

                int startX = x()[0];
                int endX = x()[1];
                int startY = y()[0];
                int endY = y()[1];

                int xy = r.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1;

                if (xy == 1) {
                    return new int[]{1, startX, endX, startY, xy};
                }

                return new int[]{1, startY, endY, startX, xy};
            }

private int[] x() {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int xLeft = (int) (13 * displaymetrics.density);
        int xRight = (int) (displaymetrics.widthPixels - (13 * displaymetrics.density));

        Random r = new Random();
        int startX = r.nextInt(xRight - xLeft) + xLeft;
        int endX = r.nextInt(xRight - xLeft) + xLeft;

        return new int[]{startX, endX};
    }

private int[] y() {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int yTop = (int) (60 * displaymetrics.density);
        int yBottom = (int) (displaymetrics.heightPixels - (51 * displaymetrics.density));

        Random r = new Random();
        int startY = r.nextInt(yBottom - yTop) + yTop;
        int endY = r.nextInt(yBottom - yTop) + yTop;

        return new int[]{startY, endY};
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full error/stacktrace that you're getting?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to help you. You need to provide us with a complete example we can run. At the moment this is impossible because some methods (e.g. `x()` and `y()`) are missing.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is because you tried accessing line[0][0] before it was initialized, there is nothing there.

By doing:

```
int[][] line = new int[3][];
```

You are only creating 1 dimension for this multidimensional array. The way to do this is either:

```
int[][] line = new int[3][SOME_NUMBER];
```

or to explicitly initialize each row:

```
int[][] line = new int[3][];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  line[i] = new int[SOME_NUMBER];
}
```

If you need to better understand it, have a look here, for example: [Multi-Dimensional Arrays in Java

][1](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting a null pointer because you made a reference to an element outside the bounds of the array. The line where you got the error on should look like this:

```
if (i > 0 && line[i][0] == 2) {
```

Instead of:

```
if (i > 0 && line[i - 1][0] == 2)
```

There are mistakes similar to this all over this program. Remember that  arrays start indexing at 0, not 1.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with accessing line[i - 1][0], or accessing line[i][0], if the memory has been allocated.